# update origin/master branch without checking that branch out

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I was under the assumption that:

```
git fetch origin
```

would update all the remote branches:

```
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/dev
```

etc.

but it turns out that doesn't seem to be the case and I can't figure out how these branches stay up to date, if it's not the case.

how can I make sure my local remote branches are up to date? perhaps I will have better luck with:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

?

Comment: ok how do I do a `git pull` on origin/master w/o checking it out?

Comment: Why don't you want to check out?

Comment: I don't want to checkout branches that I never actually want to work on because then I accidentally start working on the wrong branch - happens all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, `git fetch origin` *will* update all the remote-tracking names under `origin/*`.  Under what conditions are you not seeing this occur?  There are two common cases in modern Git:

- A *single-branch* clone maps one upstream branch to one remote-tracking name. If that's not what you want, avoid single-branch clones (or transform them into normal clones).
- Running `git fetch origin master`, for instance, limits the update to updating only `origin/master`, even if, say, `dev` on `origin` has new commits that would update `origin/dev` if you had run `git fetch origin` instead of `git fetch origin master`.

That second case is driven all the time by `git pull`, if you use it.  (I recommend avoiding `git pull` in favor of separate fetch and second-command, rebase or merge as desired.)

One last case is common in Git versions predating 1.8.2, in which `git fetch origin master` fails to update even `origin/master`, for instance.  The solution to this is to upgrade to a modern Git.